# Какое правило в русском языке имеет больше всего исключений?

Tags: орфография, правила

Цыган на цыпочках подошел к цыпленку и цыкнул цыц?
Сколько исключений по этому правилу? Количество?
Какие еще слова пишутся через "цы" в корне? "на цырлах" или на цирлах?

P.S.: почему нет метки "исключения"?

Comment: На какой вопрос (их как min пять) хотите получить ответ?